# Dagger 2 scopes in a class

Tags: android, scope, dagger-2

So i have this class which is injectable:

```
@Singleton
public class FriendMessageListImpl {

    @Inject RiotRosterManager riotRosterManager;

    @Singleton
    @Inject
    public FriendMessageListImpl() {
    }
}
```

My only component is injected in the application class:

```
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
```

---

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AppModule.class
        }
)
public interface AppComponent {


    /**
     * Core
     */
    void inject(...);
}
```

The objected are injected for the first time from a background service that it is always running.

The objects should be a singleton with the application scope, which mean one instance as long as the service lives. I'm not sure if it is the case, but for some reason the singleton seems not to have application scope. So is there any way i can force it? And which scope it is supposed to have considering that code?

From what i understood, i only have one component which is created in the application class, and altought the object itself is injected thru constructor, it shares the same scope as the component. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems that your background service is running constantly after the app is first started so the Application object stays live with it (until service is stopped and activities finished).
This seems pretty fine, you will not need to create the graph again, just get the existing instance.